# Why is a model's create method different, depending on whether it called directly or via an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I add something to a model's `create` method

**note.rb**

```
def self.create p
    p 'in self.create'
    super p
end
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :notes
```

It gets run whenever I call `Note.create`. But if I call `create` on an association, like `current_user.notes.create`, it doesn't get run. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redefine association `create` method you can pass a block with new `create` method to `has_many` association:

**user.rb:**

```
has_many :notes do
  def create
    p '123'
    super
  end
end
```